# Super in anonymous class (Java)

Tags: java, anonymous-class

Suppose we have code:

```
public class Solution {
private String name;
private String surname;

Solution(String name, String surname) {
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
}
private String getPrivate() { return name; }
public String getPublic() { return surname; }

private void sout() {
    new Solution("Anonim private", "Anonim public") {
        void printName() {
            System.out.println(getPrivate());               // Main   private
          //System.out.println(this.getPrivate());          // can't compile
            System.out.println(super.getPrivate());         // Anonym private
            System.out.println(Solution.this.getPrivate()); // Main   private

            System.out.println("\n");

            System.out.println(getPublic());                // Anonym public
            System.out.println(this.getPublic());           // Anonym public
            System.out.println(super.getPublic());          // Anonym public
            System.out.println(Solution.this.getPublic());  // Main   public

        }
    }.printName();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Solution("Main   private", "Main   public").sout();
}}
```

Comments - our output (by intellij idea)

Question: Why does `super.getPrivate()` return the string `"Anonym private"`?

If we look at Java documentation we will see that

> If your method overrides one of its superclass's methods, you can invoke the overridden method through the use of the keyword super.

But in this case is obtained another meaning of `super` word: instance of inner classes. You can check it adding:

```
System.out.println(super.getClass());
System.out.println(this.getClass());
```

Comment: I didn't see any question here. Am I missing anything?

Comment: There is no "other meaning" of `super`, which means super-class, aka base class. The base/super class of the anonymous class is the `Solution` class, and refers to the instance of the `Solution` class that goes with the instance of the anonymous class.

Comment: @user2004685 See *"**Question:** Why "super.getPrivate()" return string "Anonym private" ? "* starting in the first line below the big code block.

Comment: I think you're confused by the difference between super/sub-class and inner/outer scope.  Anything inside `sout()` that is printing "Main" is resolving to the outer scope, not the super class.  That's why `Solution.this.` always prints "Main", because it's an explicit reference to the outer class's method.

Comment: You are not overriding any methods here. Instead, you have two separate instances. One instance happens to be of an inner class. But `super` still refers to that instance. Don't expect `super` to refer to a different instance.

Comment: Also, I expect `System.out.println(getPrivate());   // Main   private` to print "Anonym private". Did you get the comment wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> Question: Why does `super.getPrivate()` return the string `"Anonym  private"`?
>
> If we look at Java documentation we will see that
>
> > If your method overrides one of its superclass's methods, you can invoke the overridden method through the use of the keyword `super`.
>
> But in this case is obtained another meaning of `super` word: instance
>   of inner classes.

No.  The meaning of `super` that you quoted is the applicable one here.  The context is this:

> ```
> private class Solution {
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> private void sout() {
>     new Solution("Anonim private", "Anonim public") {
>             void printName() {
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> ```
>                 System.out.println(super.getPrivate());
> ```

You have recognized that context as an inner class's method, so the first question to answer is *what is that inner class's superclass*, to which the `super` refers?  But that's easy: its superclass is `Solution` -- that's what the "`new Solution(...)`" part *means*.

The next question to ask is *what are the properties of that instance*?  That is also easy: it is what results from initializing it via the constructor matching the arguments provided.  Thus, it is perfectly natural and expected that `super.getPrivate()` reads back the first of those.

Since the inner class does not override `getPrivate()`, the use of `super` is needless -- the same result is obtained by invoking `getPrivate()` on the inner class instance itself, whether inside the inner class implementation or outside it.

None of that has anything to do with the containing instance of the inner class's containing class.  That the containing class is *also* `Solution` is meant to confuse and challenge you.  The containing instance is a separate object from the inner class instance.  Its methods and variables with the same name as the inner class instances' (i.e. all of them) are hidden from the inner class instance, accessible only via the `Solution.this` construct.

Comment: you forget to say as seen from Soner's decompiled codes for last paragraph, sir (:

Answer (score 0):

If you compile your code on terminal with `javac Solution.java`, there are two files whose names are `Solution.class` and `Solution$1.class` which is the (local) inner class.

Solution.class

```
public class Solution {
  private String name;
  private String surname;

  Solution(String paramString1, String paramString2) {
    name = paramString1;
    surname = paramString2; }

  private String getPrivate() { return name; }
  public String getPublic() { return surname; }


  private void sout()
  {
    new Solution.1(this, "Anonim private", "Anonim public").printName();
  }

  public static void main(String[] paramArrayOfString) { 
       new Solution("Main   private", "Main   public").sout(); 
  }
}
```

Solution$1.class

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

class Solution$1
  extends Solution
{
  Solution$1(Solution paramSolution, String paramString1, String paramString2) { 
           super(paramString1, paramString2); 
  }

  void printName() { 

    System.out.println(Solution.access$000(this$0));    // Main   private        
    System.out.println(Solution.access$000(this));      // Anonym private
    System.out.println(Solution.access$000(this$0));    // Main   private

    System.out.println("\n");

    System.out.println(getPublic());           // Anonym public
    System.out.println(getPublic());           // Anonym public
    System.out.println(super.getPublic());     // Anonym public
    System.out.println(this$0.getPublic());    // Main public
  }
}
```

As you can see `this$0` represents enclosing class object, `this` represents the (local) inner class object.

> Question: Why does `super.getPrivate()` return the string `"Anonym private"`?

Java opts to work like that as seen from its decompiled side ;)